# Call function with a parameter from another function

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a function that repeatedly calls another function.

The second function has a bool parameter that changes the way it behaves, so when I call the first function I want to have a parameter that specifies the way the second function behaves.

```
void Function1(int n, bool differentBehavior = false)
{
    int a = Function2(n, differentBehavior);
    int b = Function2(1, differentBehavior);
    int c = Function2(2, differentBehavior);

    return a + b + c;
}

int Function2(int x, bool differentBehavior)
{
     if (!differentBehavior) // do something
     else // do something else
 }
```

The code itself is obviously an example (in reality the second function is called over 20 times and for code readability I would love to not have to specify the second parameter every time), but I put it there to explain what I'm currently doing. Is there no better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your code looks "ok" to me. What is your question exactly? Do this with less lines of code? You could write a loop for the inner calls? I don't understand if you call your inner function exactly 3 times or exactly n times. That's not clear from your example.

Comment: _"Is there no better way to achieve this?"_ - no better way of _doing what_ exactly?  Without knowing exactly what `Function2` is _meant to do_ how can we decide.  Even _pseudo_ code is more informative.

Comment: Also, your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: I would love to not have to write differentBehavior as a parameter every single time I call Function2, since it never changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce a local function to capture the second argument like so:

```
int Function1(int n, bool differentBehavior = false)
{
    int func(int n) => Function2(n, differentBehavior);

    int a = func(n);
    int b = func(1);
    int c = func(2);

    return a + b + c;
}
```

This is called "partial function application". See more here:

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application/

Answer (score 2):

While C# doesn't support [true function Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) nor [first-class partial function application](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345039/why-isnt-it-common-to-hack-partial-function-application-in-c), you can always
use a new locally scoped function (aka a *local function*) to wrap your `Function2` with predefined arguments... which is conceptually *almost* the same thing as partial application, just without [referential-transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), and awkward delegate types.

---

Anyway, if you want to pass the outer `Function1`'s `differentBehavior` argument value to `Function2` then you will need to use a closure, which will capture the variable, but [this will introduce  *slight* runtime performance complications](https://wiki.c2.com/?ClosuresConsideredHarmful): as a closure generally means a GC heap allocation and copying function local state from the stack onto the heap and yada yada.

However, if you're only using *constant* parameter values - or you're okay with using different wrappers for different predefined argument values, then you can use a `static` local function (requires C# 8.0 or later) which prevents you from unintentionally creating a closure.

---

For example:

```cs
void Function1(int n, bool differentBehavior = false)
{
    // Look ma, no closure!
    static int PartiallyAppliedFunc2_False(int x) => Function2( x: x, differentBehavior: false );
    static int PartiallyAppliedFunc2_True(int x) => Function2( x: x, differentBehavior: true );

    int a = PartiallyAppliedFunc2_False(n);
    int b = PartiallyAppliedFunc2_False(1);
    int c = PartiallyAppliedFunc2_True(2);

    return a + b + c;
}

int Function2(int x, bool differentBehavior)
{
     if (!differentBehavior) // do something
     else // do something else
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look at when a lot of parameters are being passed on the stack is whether there is some higher-level state that could be represented by a member variable of the class.

Here's some code for the most basic kind of state machine. This general approach might help solve the problem you're having:

```
class Program
{
    enum Behaviors
    {
        BehaviorA,
        BehaviorB,
        BehaviorC,
    }
    static Behaviors State { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (State = Behaviors.BehaviorA; State <= Behaviors.BehaviorC; State++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Function returned { Function1(0)}");
        }

        int Function1(int n)
        {
            int a = Function2(n);
            int b = Function2(1);
            int c = Function2(2);

            return a + b + c;
        }
        int Function2(int x)
        {
            switch (State)
            {
                case Behaviors.BehaviorA:
                    return x * 10;
                case Behaviors.BehaviorB:
                    return x * 20;
                case Behaviors.BehaviorC:
                    return x * 30;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```